# Encrypting And Decrypting a string using Aes Encryption - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, encryption, aes

I wanna store an encrypted string inside a SQL Database as a byte array and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The code is this:

```
    private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string password = passwordBox.Text.ToString();

            using (Aes algorithm = Aes.Create())
            {
                byte[] encryptedPassword = EncryptString(password, algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV);

                string roundTrip = DecryptString(encryptedPassword, algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV);

                MessageBox.Show("Encrypted Password: " + encryptedPassword.ToString() + '\n' + "Round Trip: " + roundTrip.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And the code used for the 'EncryptString' and 'DecryptString' is the one from [Microsoft's Aes Class Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx) (the Example situated at the end of the page).

I executed my code and all it gives me in a Message Box is this:

> Encrypted Password: System.Byte[]
>
> Round Trip: (empty space)

```
    static byte[] EncryptString(string str, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
    {
        if (str == null || str.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("string");
        if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

        byte[] encrypted;

        using (Aes algorithm = Aes.Create())
        {
            algorithm.Key = key;
            algorithm.IV = IV;

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(str);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        return encrypted;
    }

    static string DecryptString(byte[] cipher, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
    {
        if (cipher == null || cipher.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipher");
        if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

        string decrypted;

        using (Aes algorithm = Aes.Create())
        {
            algorithm.Key = key;
            algorithm.IV = IV;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        decrypted = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return decrypted;
    }
```

Can someone help me fix it, please?

P.S. The Text Box has the Password Char setted to *

Comment: Works fine for me. Post your actual encrypt/decrypt code please.

Comment: This program works correctly for me too - with `string password = "ABCD"`, roundTrip alco contains "ABCD". What did you try as a password? Did you do any modifications to `EncryptString` and `DecryptString` methods from Microsoft's example?

Comment: You will see it better if you change your message line to MessageBox.Show("Encrypted Password: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encryptedPassword) + '\n' + "Round Trip: " + roundTrip); or something like (possibly UTF instead of ACII, depends on your character set).

Comment: Then `passwordBox.Text` is probably empty. Set breakpoints, step through your code, inspect your variables.

Comment: @KevinFord I posted my code.

Comment: That stops it working, now we have something to look at ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DecryptString` method, you forgot to pass `cipher` parameter to constructor of `msDecrypt` memory stream as an input, thus method actually deciphers empty input stream, so result is empty too.

Line

```
using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
```

should actually be:

```
using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
```

and then everything works fine.

Comment: I just found the same thing! That'll teach me to keep reading :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know that I have to pay more attention to code examples. You fixed it, I cannot believe that it was hiding so good. Now, I have another little problem. If I use Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(here are 64 characters); as key and Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(here are 32 characters); as IV, it gives me the error: "The specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm. ". Do you know how should I do this? I tried to modify the BlockSize of the Aes Algorithm but it won't work, instead, it gives me the same error message. Thanks again!

Comment: There are only 3 variants of AES: AES-128, AES-192 and AES-256. So **key size** must be 128 bits (16 bytes), 192 bits (24 bytes) or 256 bits (32 bytes). You can get valid key sizes from [LegalKeySizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalkeysizes?view=netframework-4.7) property. Also all AES variants requires **block size** of 128 bits (16 bytes) as you can see in [LegalBlockSizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalblocksizes?view=netframework-4.7) property.